# How can I view my model's progress over time instead of epochs?

Tags: tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I'm training neural networks using Tensorflow-Keras. My current code is set up to use CSVLogger to track progress over epochs, and using matplotlib pyplot to plot training vs validation for both accuracy and loss each. For both graph plots, the values are plotted against epoch # too.

Is it possible to plot my model's training progress over time instead? Meaning to say, instead of having epoch # as the x-axis, can I have execution time instead?

The reason for doing this is that I'm doing hyper-parameter tuning with early stopping, so each model may stop at different epochs, yet at the same time due to differences in architecture and configuration, the average execution time per epoch may differ too.

As such, instead of the number of epochs, it may be more informative for me to compare how long it takes for the different models' loss and accuracy to converge, and for early stopping to occur. After all, if model A can achieve a best val_loss of 0.25 in 20 epochs before stopping, at a rate of 2 minutes per epoch, do I really want to choose that over model B which achieves a best val_loss of 0.275 in 50 epochs before stopping, at a rate of 20 seconds per epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. To do so you can create your own [Keras Callback](https://keras.io/callbacks). To do so, you have to extend the [Callback](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/16bd239e34d853f3bf7ae99f14e0324f924ca371/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L275) class. I've created a very simple callback to demo how you can track the data & time for each epoch along with the scores of the model.

```py
# Import dependencies
import datetime
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks

# Create new callback
class MyHistory(callbacks.Callback):
    """Adapted from https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#L614"""

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        self.epoch = []
        self.timestamps = []
        self.history = {}

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        self.epoch.append(epoch)
        self.timestamps.append(datetime.datetime.now())
        for k, v in logs.items():
            self.history.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

# Instantiate callback
myHistory = MyHistory()

# Train model using callback
model.fit(..., callbacks=[myHistory])

# Print timestamps & losses
print(myHistory.timestamps)
print(myHistory.history['loss'])
```

You follow a similar approach to store the timestamp in a csv by extending the `[CSVLogger][3]` in a similar fashion.